In affine geometry, why are the intersections of an $E_p$ with the coordinate $E_{n-p}$'s unique points?
All numerical values in this discussion are real.
This is from Tensor Analysis for Physicists, Second Edition, by J. A. Schouten:

An $E_{0}$ is a point, an $E_{1}$ is called a straight line,
an $E_{2}$ a plane, and an $E_{n-1}$ a hyperplane. If $u_{\lambda}x^{\lambda}=0$
is the equation of a hyperplane through $O,$ the $u_{\lambda}$ are
called its (homogeneous) hyperplane coordinates. To every allowable
coordinate system in $E_{n}$ there belong $nE_{1}$'s, the coordinate
axes, $\begin{pmatrix}n\\
2
\end{pmatrix}E_{2}$'s, the coordinate planes, each determined by two axes and $\begin{pmatrix}n\\
p
\end{pmatrix}E_{p}$'s, the coordinate $E_{p}$'s; $1\le p\le n-1.$
By means of these it can be readily shown that an $E_{p}$ in $E_{n}$
is fixed by $(p+1)(n-p)$ numbers. If the coordinate
system is not special, an $E_{p}$ intersects each of the coordinate-$E_{n-p}$'s
in exactly one point. The $E_{p}$ is determined uniquely by $p+1$
of these points, and each of them can be fixed by $n-p$
numbers.

This is the first mention of coordinate $E_{p}$'s. So I assume the paragraph is definitive.  The $E_p$'s are defined as the submanifolds of $E_n$ satisfying the system of $n-p$ independent non-homogeneous equations
$$C^i_\lambda x^\lambda+C^i=0;\lambda=1,\dots ,n;i=p+1,\dots ,n$$
where the $C^i_\lambda$ and $C^i$ are constant.  The $E_p$ satisfying this system is called its null manifold, and the system is called the null form of the $E_p.$
The null manifold $E_p$ of this null form can be expressed using $p$ arbitrary parameters $\eta^b$ as
$$x^\kappa=B^\kappa_b \eta^b+B^\kappa;b=1,\dots ,p;\kappa=1,\dots,n$$
involving $n\left(p+1\right)$ constants.
Substituting this into the null form we get
\begin{align*}
0= & C_{\lambda}^{i}\left(B_{b}^{\lambda}\eta^{b}+B^{\lambda}\right)+C^{i}\\
= & C_{\lambda}^{i}B^{\lambda}+C^{i}\\
= & C_{\lambda}^{i}B_{b}^{\lambda}.
\end{align*}
A coordinate $E_{n-p}$ satisfies $p$ homogeneous equations.  The combined system of equations determining $E_{n-p}$ and $E_{p}$ has a unique solution if and only if the $n$ equations are independent. Accordingly, the above quoted paragraph seems to mean that the equations constituting the null form of our $E_p$ are independent of all of the equations determining the coordinate $E_{n-p}$'s sharing at least one point with $E_p$.  That doesn't make sense to me.
Schouten also says that two $E_p$'s having the same homogeneous part $\left\{C^i_\lambda\right\}$ are parallel and their intersection is the improper $E_{p-1}$ at infinity.  This may be the key to understanding the paragraph quoted above.
Will someone please explain the reasoning in that paragraph?

Edit to add:
This is an example I cooked up in an effort to understand the discussion.  I am introducing different notation.  I hope it is self-explanatory.
Consider the following null-form $\mathfrak{F}$ on $\mathbb{A}^{5}$
determining the 3-manifold $\mathbb{F}^{3},$ as shown:
\begin{align*}
1= & F^{1}{}_{1}=F^{2}{}_{2}\text{ else }0=F^{1}{}_{i}=F^{2}{}_{i}\\
-1= & F^{1}=F^{2}\\
0= & F^{1}{}_{i}x^{i}+F^{1}=x^{1}-1\\
= & F^{2}{}_{i}x^{i}+F^{2}=x^{2}-1\\
1= & x^{1}=x^{2}\\
\mathbb{F}^{3}= & \left\{ 1,1,x^{3},x^{4},x^{5}\right\} \subset\mathbb{A}^{5}
\end{align*}
The coordinate hyperplane produced by constraining the $i$th coordinate
to $x^{i}=0$ is written $\mathbb{A}_{\bar{i}}^{4}.$ A complenetary
notation is also shown. Similar notation for coordinate 2-submanifolds
is also shown in the following. In the case of our $\mathbb{F}^{3}$
the submanifold intersects only one of the ten coordinate 2-submanifolds.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{A}_{\bar{1}}^{4}= & \left\{ 0,x^{2},x^{3},x^{4},x^{5}\right\} =\mathbb{A}_{2345}^{4}\\
\mathbb{A}_{\bar{2}}^{4}= & \left\{ x^{1},0,x^{3},x^{4},x^{5}\right\} =\mathbb{A}_{1345}^{4},\text{etc.}\\
\mathbb{A}_{\bar{1}\bar{2}\bar{3}}^{2}= & \left\{ 0,0,0,x^{4},x^{5}\right\} =\mathbb{A}_{45}^{2}\\
\mathbb{A}_{\bar{1}\bar{2}\bar{4}}^{2}= & \left\{ 0,0,x^{3},0,x^{5}\right\} =\mathbb{A}_{35}^{2},\text{etc.}\\
\mathbb{A}_{12}^{2}= & \left\{ x^{1},x^{2},0,0,0\right\} \\
\mathbb{A}_{12}^{2}\cap\mathbb{F}^{3}= & \left\{ 1,1,0,0,0\right\} 
\end{align*}
Aparently, Schouten intendes that all of the other $\mathbb{A}_{ij}^{2}\cap\mathbb{F}^{3}\in\mathbb{A}_{ij}^{2}$
are ``points at infinity''.

I believe this involves "over-determination".  That is, there are, in general more equations than variables, so the full set of equations taken at the same time is inconsistent.  The zero-form of $E_p$ precludes $n-p$ of the zero-forms of the $E_{n-p}.$   I need to put this into coherent statements.  If anyone else beats me to  it, he or she gets the points.
